# I have a windows 10 Laptop, with Dead Screen Monitor

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, monitor-settings

is there any way of accessing my laptop without just buying a new monitor ? Remote desktop access is not configured . I have another laptop and pc if there is any cheap solution , any cheap gadget i can take to access my laptop with the dead screen? Or any phone application? 
Thank you

Comment: Plug in an external monitor.

Comment: you are right,I'm sorry, i fixed it. I just want to access the laptop with the dead screen, without buying a new monitor, or without remote desktop thing from windows .

Answer (score 0):

- Borrow a monitor, which should work through Windows Plug 'n Play.
- Configure Remote Desktop or install a similar tool such as [Team Viewer or an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/remote-desktop-connection/).
- Unplug the borrowed monitor.

**However, if you have access to a computer with a monitor**, use a [KVM switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042G49XM) to share the display... and the keyboard and mouse, as well, if you wish.